# how to parse to get correct numbers

Tags: javascript

Having trouble figuring out how to get the correct numbers to set some variables when i read API item

Here is item in API - `h2hwlt="15&#8209;12&#8209;3"`

I need to get the numbers 15 , 12 and 3 to set as variables

```
var wins = parseInt(response.leagueStandings.franchise[i].h2hwlt); // i want only # '15' here
var losses = parseInt(response.leagueStandings.franchise[i].h2hwlt); // i want only # '12' here
var ties = parseInt(response.leagueStandings.franchise[i].h2hwlt); // i want only # '3' here
```

Comment: Split it by `&#8209;` (which is non breaking dash btw)

Comment: ... `const [wins, losses, ties] = h2hwlt.split('&#8209;')`

Comment: unfortunately being a novice I'm not really understanding without some visual code

Comment: @MShack you can use `const [wins, losses, ties] = h2hwlt.split('&#8209;').map(parseInt)` instead of your code. The key here is `split` function though. Learn about it and try to implement one on your own - if you don't want to be novice.